# Ubuntu-Unity3D All Compiler Errors Problem

Tags: unity

Before 2 weeks ago I can develop games on Ubuntu with Unity3D but after some updates or somethings I give "***all compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter play mode***" messages. If I compile code on Intellij Rider it's ok, no problem. There is nothing on Unity console and I am researching about it since 2 weeks but I can not find any solution. I tried to install mono and .net core, yesterday find line ending problem an try to different editor but they don't work.

Produce Steps:

- Create new 2D project
- Add empty object to scene
- Add script to empty object
- Compile

ubuntu: 18.04

unity3d: 2017.4.26f1 and 2019.1

Comment: It doesn't look like we have enough information about the code that Unity thinks is generating a compiler error for us to be able to reproduce this issue. Can you reproduce the problem in a new, empty project? Try to provide us with a minimal, complete, verifiable example that fits into the body of your question (not an external link), so other users with Ubuntu can test it. If you don't think it's anything in your code or project setup that's at issue, then this might be a bug to report to Unity support instead.

Comment: I added produce steps. Script is created from scratch.

Comment: And you don't get any errors when you compile the project?

Comment: This is just the default script template, with no additional typing whatsoever? Did you name the script anything in particular?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I get error but can not see on console, only red exclamation but it compiled on Rider from Intellij.

Comment: @DMGregory There is no strange char in script name, I tried different naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find solution. First, I tried to compile on MonoDevelop and it compiled successfully but one error. It was about `/usr/lib/mono/*` after than I changed owner for this directory with `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/lib/mono/` and it works!